# Unable to create an Opportunity Product "+" button on sub-grid not working

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Since the update "CRM Online 2015 Update (7.1.1.4314) (DB 7.1.1.4309)"  the "+" button to add new opportunity product stop working, nothing happens when clicking on it.

I found same problem here https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/176528 but I didn't add any customization to the form neither change the name of the sub-grid(current name "opportunityproducts").

Is there anything that can be affecting the behavior of this specific button?

I tried creating a new form but same problem, only que "+" on the Quote sub-grid works.

Comment: Are you a system admin?  I ask because of potential new requirements with security roles.  Do you have any solutions interacting with your products site map?  If neither one of these options work, I would use f12 Dev tools in IE to view the events of the button.  Watch the dom as you click the button and see if the onclick changes for a brief period of time.

Comment: Yes I'm a system, I checked the dom and nothing seems to be changing still not sure whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

The name of sub-grid should be "opportunityproductsGrid"